# Function to group department based on code not giving expected results python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a data frame with column with numbers.

##### example dataframe

| Year | Code | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 530010 | 11728.7 |
| 2022 | 540060 | 4793.21 |
| 2022 | 514008 | -15665.40 |
| 2022 | 540860 | 6991.10 |
| 2022 | 540060 | 1382.00 |

I have following function to assign each code to category to make a new column

##### function you bucket code into departments

```
    def department_group (Code): 
        if (Code == '514008') or (Code == '215080') or  (Code == '215980'):
            return 'Accounting and Administration'
        elif (Code == '515000') :
            return 'Customer Services'
        elif (Code == '540060') or (Code == '550010')  or (Code == '550012')  or (Code == '550028') :
            return 'Maintenance Department'
        elif (Code == '220000') or (Code == '220992') or (Code == '220095') :
            return 'Management'
        elif (Code == '550000')  or (Code == '550055') or (Code == '550060') or (Code == '550065') :
            return 'Marketing Department'
        elif ((Code == '530010') or (Code == '540860') or (Code == '560016') or  (Code == '570000')
          or (Code == '570010') or (Code == '570020')) :
            return 'Sales Department'            
        else:
            return Code

df['department'] = df['Code'].apply(department_group )
df['department'].value_counts()
```

However, when I count categories the don't match my code counts.
Any suggestion/better way to address the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would change this to a np.select() to make it easier to read

```
#Accounting and Administration
a_and_a = ['514008', '215080', '215980']
#Customer Services
customer_service = ['515000']
#Maintenance Department
m_d = ['540060', '550010', '550012', '550028']
#Management
management_lst = ['220000', '220992', '220095']
#Marketing Department
m_and_d = ['550000', '550055', '550060', '550065']
#Sales Department
s_d = ['530010', '540860', '560016', '570000', '570010', '570020']  

cond_lst = [df.Code.isin(a_and_a), df.Code.isin(customer_service), df.Code.isin(m_d), df.Code.isin(management_lst), df.Code.isin(m_and_d), df.Code.isin(s_d)]
choice_lst = ['Accounting and Administration', 'Customer Services', 'Maintenance Department', 'Management' , 'Marketing Department', 'Sales Department']
df['Department'] = np.select(cond_lst, choice_lst, 'Missing')
df
```

This is nice because it is easily expandable, and organized. If you like the def better then that is also an option, but this might help it be easier to read and resolve your problem.

Comment: thanks, but i have many comparison i think for that function is more robust than this approach?

Comment: I updated my answer which should be all of your departments.

Comment: When I used the np.select() I was able to get the results expected by counting up the departments.

Comment: thanks, strangely my count are not right, i got everything in missign with few in needed departments